# Allocate a dynamic array of pointers to the structure

Tags: c++

I have created the dynamic array

```
struct Student{
    string name;
    string dateOfBirth;
};

Student **students = new Student*[5]
```

But I'm getting error when I try to store data

Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was 0xCDCDCDCD.

```
(*students[iterator]).name = name;
```

Comment: why do you want an array of pointers rather than an array of `Student`s? You only have an array of pointers, but there is no `Student` whose name you could assign to

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the type of and value at `students[0]` after you allocate the array? Where does it point to? Also, better mention that you cannot use `std::vector` because that is the standard solution.

Comment: The assignment is to dynamically allocate memory. I can't use vector. And I have to assign this in some function. And use in another without passing any parameters. I'm sorry I'm not that familiar with dynamic memory.

Comment: If you have a pointer to a struct, you access the fields with the `->` operator, e.g `students[i]->name = name;`

Comment: Also be aware of the fact that you are being taught bad habits.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.
I have tried that too. But it still doesn't store data. Should I try to use malloc?

Comment: Still, why use `Studen*` instead of `Student`? `Student *students = new Student[5]` will work just fine. But it is bad C++.

Comment: No, you should not try malloc. It will not work. You should post a [mcve].

Comment: You also should understand that a pointer to `Student` needs a `Student` to function. Are there any `Student`s in your program? Show where you create them.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Thanks for your time good sir. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allocate memory like this:

```cpp
struct Student{
    string name;
    string dateOfBirth;
};

Student **students = new Student*[5];
```

Just like the comments say, you need to think about what the datatype of `students[0]` actually is. In this case, it's a `Student *`, meaning you have to treat it as such. If you try to assign a value directly to that by doing something like the following, you'll get all sorts of memory errors (and hopefully compiler errors/warnings)

```cpp
Student **students = new Student*[5];

students[0] = Student{"Bob", "1st Jan 1970"}; // Nope
*students[0] = Student{"Bill", "1st Jan 1970"}; // Also no
```

The first one clearly won't work, because we're trying to assign a `Student` to a `Student *`, which isn't possible. The reason for the second one not working is to do with how memory allocation works.

When you call `Student **students = new Student*[5]`, you're telling the compiler to allocate memory for 5 `Student *` objects, which are all ultimately just 64bit unsigned integers. That means there is memory available for those 64x5 bits, but remember, they're pointers, so they need to point somewhere.

The way to assign a value to would be something like the following:

```cpp
students[0] = new Student{"Barry", "1st Jan 1970"}; // (Notice the 'new')
```

This will dynamically allocate memory for a new `Student` and set the pointer in `students` to point to it, allowing you to access it.

---

======== A Warning ========

When you allocate memory dynamically (i.e. using `new` or `malloc`, etc.) you are responsible for calling `delete[]` or `delete` or `free`, depending on the situation. Without these calls, the memory will never be freed and you'll end up with a memory leak, which can be very problematic. The difficulty with using a pointer to pointers is that you'll need to free each sub-pointer before freeing the main pointer. Trying to do it the other way around will lead to other fun problems which you're better off just not having to suffer through.

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if anything could be cleared up or if it doesn't work...

Comment: Glad to hear it. Do you think you could mark this answer as correct so anyone else with a similar problem can find it more easily?